# IOS collection view scrolling stuck because of refreshControl

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uirefreshcontrol

Hi In my application I am using refreshControl for my collection view. It's working fine. Only thing is that when I try to scroll my collection view it stuck at some point. But if I remove refreshControl then its working fine. I am not using UICollectionView controller. I am using UIviewcontroller with collection view delegate. I am doing following things.

```
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
self.refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(reloadData) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.collectionView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
```

It got stuck at some point. Is there anyone knows about this? Need Help. Thank you.

Comment: I created a demo of uicollectionview and added refreshcontrol but didn't faced any scroll issue. It was working fine for me.

Comment: Are u doing same thing which I am doing? I am displaying images.

Comment: yes @nilkash... I created a demo just for learning and implemented the refresh control in it.